# How to track unused resources in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have been using AWS for a while now. I always have the difficulty tracking AWS resources and how they are interconnected. Obviously, I am using Terraform but still, there is always ad-hoc operations that cut down my visibility.

Since I have been charged multiple times for resources/services that are present but not used by me.

Unused services include resources that are not pointing to other services but present in the AWS environment.

Tools suggestions are also welcome.

Also, posted on [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/how-to-track-unused-resources-in-aws/). Posting here since there are fewer people there.

Answer (score 4):

I have used [Janitor Monkey](https://github.com/Netflix/SimianArmy/wiki/Janitor-Home), [Cloud Custodian](https://github.com/capitalone/cloud-custodian) and we do have a bunch of AWS Config + Lambda for cleaning up.

> [Janitor Monkey](https://github.com/Netflix/SimianArmy/wiki/Janitor-Home) determines whether a resource should be a cleanup
>   candidate by applying a set of rules on it. If any of the rules
>   determines that the resource is a cleanup candidate, Janitor Monkey
>   marks the resource and schedules a time to clean it up.

Answer (score 3):

I think that a viable answer here is the same as the popular answer for when to [auto-scale](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-policy.html) - [use CloudWatch alarms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/scaling_plan.html).

Whenever you have a service that you need to auto-scale up, you do something like [monitor for high CPU](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_AlarmAtThresholdEC2.html). If the CPU usage trips some threshold, the alarm can be configured to scale up your fleet. Correspondingly, if CPU usage goes below some threshold, the alarm can be configured to scale down the fleet. Similar alarms can be configured other alerts like [memory, disk usage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html), etc.

So, instead of configuring CloudWatch alarms to scale up or scale down your fleet, you can just configure a CloudWatch alarm to email you when a host becomes idle (e.g. [it's CPU usage is too low](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_AlarmAtThresholdEC2.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Janitor Monkey, I've created a tool to track different types of unused resources (ELB, EBS, AMI, Security groups, etc) : https://github.com/romibuzi/majordome

Answer (score 0):

I also had this question, so I decided to write a simple Go application that can find unused services in all regions. You can find it here:

https://github.com/ku9nov/aws-explorer

At the moment, it doesn't search for many resources, but those that can be lost and forgotten. It's especially useful for cost savings and maintaining order.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33954195)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).